# Calling ant exec command giving file not found error

Tags: ant, exec

I have simple code to call "Cypress" from the ant file.

1)I have configured the cypress path in PATH env

2)I can fire cypress command from anywhere from the command prompt

```
<exec executable="cypress" 
  dir="C:\rockwell\CypressAutomation\node_modules\.bin\cypress">
</exec>
```

Above code gives me the error saying JAva.io.exception; cypress not found in the dir ""C:\rockwell\CypressAutomation\node_modules.bin"".

I have tried it without "dir" attribut also; resulting in the same error.

Comment: It should work as long as it's included in the system's PATH, so there's probably some small detail (typo, lack of capitalization, missing file extension, etc) that's messing it up somewhere. Failing that, you could just put the full path to the file inside the `executable` attribute and not rely on PATH at all.

Comment: I  did it, by giving full path executable itself; Its giving me the diff error as ;"CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Comment: Fixed it jyst by adding the extension to the command as .cmd